# How can I change an Optuna's trial result?

Tags: machine-learning, optuna

I'm using optuna on a complex ML algorithm, where each trial takes around 3/4 days. After a couple of trials, I noticed that the values that I was returning to optuna were incorrect, but I do have the correct results on another file (saving as a backup). Is there any way I could change this defectives results directly in the study object?

I know I can export the study in a pandas dataframe using `study.trials_dataframe()` and then change it there? However, I need to visualize it in optuna-dashboard, so I would need to directly change it in the study file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `Study`, use [create_trial](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.trial.create_trial.html#optuna.trial.create_trial) to create trials with correct values and use [Study.add_trials](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.study.Study.html#optuna.study.Study.add_trials) to insert them into the new study.

```py
old_trials = old_study.get_trials(deepcopy=False)
correct_trials = [
    optuna.trial.create_trial(
        params=trial.params,
        distributions=trial.distributions,
        value=correct_value(trial.params)
    ) for trial in old_trials]
new_study = optuna.create_study(...)
new_study.add_trials(correct_trials)
```

Note that Optuna doesn't allow you to change existing trials once they are finished, i.e., successfully returned a value, got pruned, or failed. (This is an intentional design; Optuna uses caching mechanisms intensively and we don't want to have inconsistencies during distributed optimization.)
You can only create a new study containing correct trials, and optionally delete the old study.

Answer (score -1):

`study.get_trials(deepcopy=False)` can return editable trials.

Though it won't change attributes (such as `study.best_trial`) automatically.

Comment: As a developer of Optuna, I would say "please never do that". `get_trials(deepcopy=False)` will return Optuna's internal cache object, trusting that users don't modify them (it is intended to be used from samplers where the cost of a deep copy is unacceptable). Modifying the returned object will not change the underlying storage, and we cannot promise what will happen.